# Couldn't connect to database using Cloud SQL proxy

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When using the GCloud CLI to create the service accounts and keys I get the following error

```
2018/02/24 22:32:35 New connection for "moodle-proj-10:europe-west2:mysqlinst10"
2018/02/24 22:32:35 couldn't connect to "moodle-proj-10:europe-west2:mysqlinst10": ensure that the account has access to "moodle-proj-10:europe-west2:mysqlinst10" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during createEphemeral for moodle-proj-10:europe-west2:mysqlinst10: googleapi: Error 403: The client is not authorized to make this request., notAuthorized
```

When I delete the service accounts and corresponding keys are re-create it using the console, the error changes to the error below

```
2018/02/24 23:21:25 couldn't connect to "moodle-proj-10:europe-west2:mysqlinst10": Post https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/moodle-proj-10/instances/mysqlinst10/createEphemeral?alt=json: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Invalid JWT Signature."
}
```

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Google Cloud Support here. I've inspected your project and I can see that you've got a Cloud SQL instance named "mysqlinst10".

I can see that the error output you've provided is referring to connection errors:

If the error you've reported is happening when connecting to a Cloud SQL instance then:

Review the roles the service account is using to connect to the MySQL instance and set the adequate ones. Check that the Cloud API access scope is enabled for Cloud SQL in the instance.

Comment: Can you provide the commands that are throwing the error messages? 
Are you getting this errors when trying to connect to the mysqlinst10 ? Where is this mysqlinst10 connecting to/from (GKE, GCE, other)? 

Please confirm if you are getting this error when creating/deleting service account/service account keys, when connecting to the Cloud SQL instance or while performing other actions (please specify which action and provide the command).

Comment: Paula, I deleted the service account and keys and manually recreated it using the console. Everything worked just fine. I will have another go later with the APIs to confirm if the issue is associated with the API.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I followed the command line instructions in this [help article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)

Solution is to delete the original service account and create a new one in the console using [this help article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app).

Comment: IMHO it would be useful summarizing here the contents of the linked articles instead of simply linking them.